# How to cluster/identify points away from a regression line

Tags: clustering, linear-regression

For many vine plots, I have NDVI and Leaf Area values for each vine.
I already know that NDVI and LA has a strong positive correlation as you can see in this picture.
[image]

But as you can see too, there are some points away from this pool of points.
How can I cluster or identify these points?
I'm using Python with sklearn, scipy and other libs like them.

[image]

Comment: This is called `outlier detection`. There are many ways to do it and the algorithm that performs best depends on the details of your case.

Comment: Ok, thank you @louic, I'll try this!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment, there are some methods to detect outliers. The best known might be Cook‘s distance in (or after) regression. In essence you look for observations with a high residual.

Here is a short [R tutorial](http://r-statistics.co/Outlier-Treatment-With-R.html). Here is a short [Python approach](https://songhuiming.github.io/pages/2016/11/27/linear-regression-in-python-outliers-leverage-detect/).